# How to show captcha challenge dialog all time of submission

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement google reCaptcha. My code:

```
private fun onClick() {
SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(CAPTCHA_KEY)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { response ->
            if (!response.tokenResult.isEmpty()) {
                verify(response.tokenResult)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
            if (e is ApiException) {
                Log.d("asd", "Error message: " + CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.statusCode))
            } else {
                Log.d("asd", "Unknown type of error: " + e.message)
            }
        }
```

}
When i click on button, reCaptcha show dialogs with several images where user should pick all images with cars, gidrants etc.

But, sometimes. After I click on the button, I always receive onSuccess callback, and the dialog never shows.

How could I control to show image to select?

Comment: If I do not know wrong, you can not decide it. Sometimes captcha directly call onSuccess sometimes show image picker also it may be want to complete two different image selection. First select cars then select bridges for example

Comment: is there any ways to show image picker?or have some api ?

Comment: I do not think so